# How to catch SIGTERM signal to process stuff in app and then terminate in Java

Tags: java, spring, hook, shutdown, sigterm

So basically my app does some processing of stuff in intervals every 1 second. I have to implement a SIGTERM signal to my app but I have to let the stuff that is currently being processed in app to **FINISH** and then the app can terminate. Therefore I'm looking for something like a try{}catch{} but for SIGTERM, I would do a sleep for few seconds and then let the SIGTERM terminate the app, is there something like that?

As far as I know **@PreDestroy** closes whole context and then leaves one bean annotated with it, executes it and then destroys.

Also the **addShutdownHook()** is a method to be run when shutting down app, but I just want my main processing to finish and then shutdown everything.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: How do you schedule the async process that runs every 1 second? Do you use `@Scheduled` annotation?

Comment: Yes, it's @Scheduled and runs every 1 second, i'd just make a flag on start of this method and set it when catching a SIGTERM so no new data is being processed, but i still have to process the already processing data when receiving SIGTERM.

Answer (score 0):

The scheduled tasks are handled by Spring's `TaskExecutor` you can configure it to set a max wait time before termination and set a flag to wait for the task on shutdown.

You can configure the `TaskExecutor` by creating a custom ThreadPoolTaskExecutor bean.

For example:

```java
@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    taskExecutor.initialize();
    return taskExecutor;
}
```

Additionally, you can set the option for max wait time:

```java
taskExecutor.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(60);
```

the reason behind this:

> Though we've configured to wait for ongoing and queued-up tasks to complete, Spring continues with the shutdown of the rest of the container. This could release resources needed by our task executor and cause the tasks to fail.

You can read more [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-graceful-shutdown)